# How to trigger ngbDropdown methods from parent component in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, ng-bootstrap

I'm using `NgbDropdown` in my angular application. I have two components **CompParent** and **CompChild**. Where **compChild** holds the HTML for dropdown and it is included into **CompParent**. I'm trying close all the opened dropdowns in page when a scroll event happens on `scrollable-div`.

comp-child.component.html:

```html
<div ngbDropdown container="body">
  <button class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm" ngbDropdownToggle>Actions</button>
  <div ngbDropdownMenu>
    <button ngbDropdownItem>Edit</button>
    <button ngbDropdownItem>Duplicate</button>
    <button ngbDropdownItem>Move</button>
    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
    <button ngbDropdownItem>Delete</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

And **CompChild** is included into **CompParent** like this:

comp-parent.component.html

```html
<div class="scrollable-div" (scroll)="closeAllDropdowns($event)">
  <div class="dropdown-container" *ngFor="let item of items">
    <app-comp-child></app-comp-child>
  </div>
</div>
```

What i have tried so far is:

in **compParent** TS:

```js
export class compParentComponent{

  @ViewChild(NgbDropdown) private readonly dropdown: NgbDropdown;

  @HostListener('scroll', ['$event'])
  closeAllDropdowns(event) {
    this.dropdown.close();
  }

}
```

But `this.dropdown` returns `undefined` and says close method is not a function associated with it. Also i tried to select all dropdowns using templateRef, that too didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@ViewChild` and `@ViewChildren` can only query elements from the component itself, not from childs. The possible option is to have a public reference to dropdown inside child, have reference to childs inside parent.

Parent:

```
export class CompParentComponent{
  @ViewChildren(CompChild) compChild!: QueryList<CompChild>;

  @HostListener('scroll', ['$event'])
  closeAllDropdowns(event) {
    this.compChild.forEach(dropdown => dropdown.close());
  }

}
```

Child:

```
export class CompChildComponent{

  @ViewChild(NgbDropdown) public dropdown: NgbDropdown;

}
```

Comment: Works like charm. Saved my day. Thanks!